# Python Encoding Comment Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encoding, comments

Originally, I've learned to specify the source code encoding in Python 2.7 this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Now I just noticed, that PEP263 also allows this:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

Is there any differences between these? What about editor compatiblity, cross-platform etc.?

What about Python 3? Is this comment still needed for python 3 or is any code in python 3 expected to be utf-8 by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [PEP3120](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/) which changed the default encoding of python source code to be UTF-8

For python 3.x one therefore finds in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations):

> If a comment in the first or second line of the Python script matches
>   the regular expression coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+), this comment is
>   processed as an encoding declaration [...] The **recommended** forms of an
>   encoding expression are:
>
> ```
> # -*- coding: <encoding-name> -*-
> ```
>
> which is recognized also by GNU Emacs, and
>
> ```
> # vim:fileencoding=<encoding-name>
> ```
>
> which is recognized by Bram Moolenaar’s VIM.
>   If no encoding declaration is found, the **default encoding is UTF-8**

The take home message is therefore:

1. python 3.x does not neccessarily need to have utf-8 specified, since it is the default
2. The way the coding line is written is to some degree personal choice (only a recommendation in the docs), it only has to match the regex.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3 the default encoding is utf-8. You can still change the encoding using the special-formatted comment `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-`.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) recommend to use this coding expression as it is recognized also by GNU Emacs.

As python checks whether the first two lines are matching the regex `coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+)`, 
`# coding=utf-8` works also to ensure utf-8 encoding but it is not recognized by GNU Emacs.